# Why is TensorBoard not showing any data?

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, tensorboard, multi-agent, pettingzoo

I'm running code to train a PPO policy on chess using [PettingZoo](https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/PettingZoo):

```py
import gym.vector.utils
import supersuit as ss
import stable_baselines3.ppo
import pettingzoo.classic

if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    env = original_env = pettingzoo.classic.chess_v5.env()
    env = pettingzoo.utils.turn_based_aec_to_parallel(env)
    env = ss.pettingzoo_env_to_vec_env_v1(env)
    env = ss.concat_vec_envs_v1(env, 8, num_cpus=4, base_class='stable_baselines3')
    model = stable_baselines3.PPO(stable_baselines3.ppo.MultiInputPolicy, env,
                                  tensorboard_log='my_logs')
    model.learn(total_timesteps=100)
```

In the next to last line, you can see I'm outputting logs to TensorBoard, where I hope to see a nice graph. However, all I see is this:

[image]

I've used TensorBoard before and it worked. Why isn't it showing any progress now? Or even lack of progress?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to use a lower value for `n_steps`.